# Retrieve latest 5 Core Data NSManagedObjects order by attribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

as mentioned in the title, I am having some issues searching on how to fetch the latest 5 records in a Core Data Entity.

I have an entity with attributes `a, b and date`, I want to receive an array that contains the latest 5 records based on `date`. In SQL, it'd probably be something like `ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5` but I am not too sure how to write the `NSPredicate` for Swift.

Comment: What issues are you having? Please show your code so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same in CoreData:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 5
```

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506622-fetchlimit) for the docs on fetchLimit.